# Netsuite - security message

Tags: netsuite

When I enter user id and password in netsuite every time it asks me my security questions , how can I stop this happening every time. Other people in my team are not having similar issue so I wonder what needs to be changed in my settings

*Note: I am not having administrator role

Answer (score 2):

NetSuite saves a cookie in your browser in order to recognize your machine and browser the next time you log on.  If it does not find this cookie it will ask a security question.  There are several conditions under which this can occur:

1. You log on using a different machine.
2. You use the same machine, but a different browser.
3. You use 'private browsing' or 'incognito' mode.
4. You use a browser extension or other program which automatically deletes your browser cache, or cookies, when you exit.
5. You have your browser itself set to empty cache on exit. E.G.: Chrome has a setting to "Keep local data only until you quit your browser"
6. Anything else that might interfere with cookies.

You'll need to check which of these apply to you and act accordingly.  If you're still unsure what could be causing it, you could reset your browser to defaults, or install a completely new browser and test whether it still happens with that.  You may need to disable or uninstall any browser extensions too.